# Pythonic way to delete an item completely from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering if there is a pythonic way to delete an item completely from a dictionary. To illustrate that, consider the dict given below:

```
mydict = {'A': ['B', 'O'],
          'B': ['A'],
          'C': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'O'],
          'D': ['E', 'C', 'F'],
          'E': ['C', 'D', 'F', 'O'],
          'F': ['C', 'D', 'E'],
          'G': ['H', 'O'],
          'H': ['G', 'O'],
          'O': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H']}
```

And let's say, I want to remove `'E'` from the dictionary. Then I expect to get such a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'A': ['B', 'O'],
          'B': ['A'],
          'C': ['D', 'F', 'O'],
          'D': ['C', 'F'],
          'F': ['C', 'D', ],
          'G': ['H', 'O'],
          'H': ['G', 'O'],
          'O': ['A', 'C', 'G', 'H']}
```

Of course, I can get it by looping over its keys and values. But, I am wondering if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: @tobias_k: the values also need cleaning.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, thanks for pointing out. Totally missed that part!

Comment: Just a meta-comment: an 'E' that appears as a *key* is a completely different beast from an 'E' that appears as an *entry in a list* that is a *value*. So it shouldn't be surprising that there's no unified way to handle both cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there are no other options here than a full set of loops, as you need to remove any `'E'` strings from your *values*:

```
{k: [i for i in v if i != 'E'] for k, v in mydict.iteritems() if k != 'E'}
```

This rebuilds your dictionary, removing the `'E'` key while we are at it, leaving you with a new dictionary that is entirely `'E'`-less.

If you want anything more efficient, you'll need to add more information. An index of positions for example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

reverse_node_map = defaultdict(set)
for k, nodes in mydict.iteritems():
    for node in nodes:
        reverse_node_map[node].add(k)
```

and then use `reverse_node_map` to pinpoint what lists to update when you want to delete a node. You'd have to keep the index up-to-date with any mutations, of course.

You should also consider replacing the `list` values with `set`s if order isn't important and the nodes are unique. Removing elements from sets is a lot more efficient and would only requiring looping over all the values of `mydict`, forgoing the nested loop over the elements of the lists. Combined with the reverse index, you can then delete nodes much more efficiently.

Comment: OK, I thought there may be a magic command that I don't know. Thanks for your comments and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple line answer in python. Maybe you can try:

```
  mydict.pop('E', None)
```

This will remove the keys with 'E' from dictionary. Now for removing 'E' values:

```
for key in mydict.keys(): 
    mydict[key].remove('E')
```

Further reference for this methods can be found on: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is no use in popping the key from the dictionary, then set it back again; just `mydict[key].remove('E')` would do.

Comment: I can do nothing but agree!